A couple gives a lift to a stranger who later kills one of them actually being paid by the other
I'm searching for a movie that I watched some time ago. Unfortunately, now I have only vague memories of the plot. Most probably, it's a US movie.
So the movie is about a couple. They drive in a car. It's night and raining. I guess that they find a man on the road and decided to give him a lift. He may be hurt or just pretended to look that way.
The couple is travelling to a special place for them - either a remoted country house or even a small personal island.
I guess in the end three of them (the couple and the stranger) are in that house. And a murder occurred. I don't really remeber who murdered whom but it turned out that the stranger is not really a stranger but was paid for either by the wife or by the husband to kill the other. So it's suspens with a twisted ending.

Would you say it's from recent years? I can think of at least 2 movies from the last decade that kind of fit (except that in both of them, they meet the stranger in daylight).

Yes. Pierce Brosnan Gerard Butler starrer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_on_a_Wheel also very similar but in that the couple meet the stranger in the day time

This might be it: Dark Harbor from 1998. From Wiki:

David Weinberg (Alan Rickman), a lawyer in his 50s, and his much younger wife Alexis (Polly Walker), drive through a torrential rainstorm to get the last ferry to their private island. They catch sight of an injured young man (Norman Reedus) at the side of the road, whom they reluctantly drive to the nearest town.

The stranger seduces the wife and eventually convinces her to eat a poisonous mushroom. In the end, he turns out to be the husband's lover; they planned her death together. However, I don't think the husband actually pays him. The entire movie is available on Youtube though with crappy audio (it sounds like it all takes place in a pipe).
